# Как в C объявить функцию с переменным числом аргументов?

Tags: c

Функция `printf` может принимать разное количество аргументов. Например:

```
printf("Hello!\n");
```

или

```
printf("Hello, %s!\n", "world");
```

Как это делается?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть стандартный заголовок `<stdarg.h>`, который позволяют объявлять подобные функции.

```
#include <stdarg.h>

void _printf(char *format, ...) {
    va_list argp;

    va_start(argp, format);

    printf(format, argp);

    va_end(argp);
}
```

Comment: `printf` -> `vprintf`?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

/* calculate sum of a 0 terminated list */
int sum(int i, ...)
{
   va_list ap;
   int arg;
   int total = i;

   va_start(ap,i);
   while ((arg = va_arg(ap,int)) != 0) {
      total += arg;
   }
   va_end(ap);
   return total;
}

int main(void)
{
   printf("The total of 1+2+3+4 is %d\n",sum( 1,2,3,4,0));
   return 0;
}
```