# Как в C передать в функцию переменное количество аргументов?

Tags: c, функции

Есть функция, которая завершает программу, выполняя занесение отладочной информации в файл лога:

```
void crash(const char *const _fstr, ...)
{
    if ( (_fstr != NULL) && (strlen(_fstr) > 0) )
    {
        FILE *f = fopen(CRASH_LOG_FILE_NAME, "a");
        fprintf(f, _fstr, ???);
        fclose(f);
    }

    abort();
}
```

Я хочу сделать, чтобы в функцию `crash()` передавалась строка формата и какое-то количество аргументов. Ситуации бывают разные. При некоторых крашах в файл желательно заносить не только строку с описанием проблемы, но еще и ряд кодов, например `GetLastError()` и `WSAGetLastError()`.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Переменное кол-во аргументов можно передать, например, в виде массива + длинна массива. Внутри функции проанализировать и выстроить нужную логику.

Comment: Мне не нужно ничего анализировать, анализировать строку формата должна fprintf(). Как ей передать набор аргументов?

Comment: @Максим через запятую.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в C объявить функцию с переменным числом аргументов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/408/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать функцию `vfprintf`, а передавать ей аргумент типа `va_list`, который получаете в своей функции примерно как

```
void crash(const char *const _fstr, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, _fstr);

    ...
    vfprintf(f,_fstr,ap);

    ...
    va_end(ap);
```

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался.